# How to use pattern funtions to in matching?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, match

I am trying to see if I can use match instead of if-else in this case, this is the code I would like to be able to write

```rust
let c : char = 'c';
let tt: TokenType = match c {
  is_alphanumeric(c) => TokenType::Identifier,
  is_whitespace(c)   => TokenType::Whitespace,
  _otherwise         => TokenType::Operator
};
// These are methods of char
pub fn is_alphanumeric(self) -> bool {}
pub fn is_whitespace(self) -> bool {}
```

With if-elses that would look like

```rust
let c : char = 'c';
let mut mut_tt : TokenType;
if c.is_alphabetic() {mut_tt = TokenType::Identifier;}
  else if c.is_whitespace() {mut_tt = TokenType::Whitespace;}
    else {mut_tt = TokenType::Operator;}
let tt : TokenType = mut_tt;
```

Is there any way I could make it work with matching instead? And should I even want to?

Comment: A function is not a pattern. You can use a function in a [guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards), but that's in addition to the pattern. Should you want to use a `match` in that case? I can't see it. It might make sense if there was an API which returned the [*general category*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_character_property#General_Category) of a character, but that's not the case for the Rust stdlib. [icu_properties](https://icu4x.unicode.org/doc/icu_properties/enum.GeneralCategory.html) has that.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this did exactly what I wanted

```rust
let tt: TokenType = match c {
    i if i.is_alphanumeric() => Some(TokenType::Identifier),
    w if w.is_whitespace() => Some(TokenType::Whitespace),
    _ => Some(TokenType::Operator)
}};
```